# Cell height changes as device height changes using Autolayout?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, height, cell

I have row height as 80 px height in iPhone 5s screen size but when table appears on iPhone 6+ it's same as the as iPhone 5s. Can we adjust the ratio of height and width of cell using `Auto layout`?

Comment: I do not think auto layout  effect inside a table view. On iOS7 , you get even a crash if you try to add a subview to table view using auto layout. You can use setRowHeight  to set different values according to different phone size

Comment: try to set height in heightForRowAtIndexPath method according to different screen size.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with `Autolayout`. You should do it programmatically but It's very easy.
You have to implement a 'method' from `UITableviewDelegate`:

`- tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

And set the cell height depending on device screen height. For example:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   return UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.height/7;
}
```

Comment: thanks for writing but I was looking for using auto layout I knew by using delegate.

Comment: Ok, then take a look to this post. I think It can help to you: https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/ios-8-tutorial-series-auto-sizing-table-cells